# How do I send a value from the server side in ASP.NET MVC Core to the Navigation page to disable an item menu ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I want to have access to a property that I set in code somewhere before the page is shown. How do I set this value since there is no CONTROLLER for a navigation page?  Is there a way to call a server side method from the RAZOR syntax?

```
  <div id="responsive-panel">
        @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
          .Name("Menu")
          .Items(items =>
          {
              items.Add()
                  .Text("Home")
                  .Action("Index", "Home");
              items.Add()
                  .Text("My Profile")
                  .Action("Index", "Profile");
              items.Add()
                  .Text("Explore")
                  .Action("Index", "Explore");
              items.Add()
                  .Text("My Comparison")
                  .Action("Index", "Comparison").Enabled(false);
          })
        )
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this a "Razor Page" or is this just Razor syntax in a view (A razor page can include what is essentially the controller where you could set the property in the OnGet and then reference it from the model which basically is the class of that page).

Comment: Razor syntax. I think the answer seems to be use a View Component

Answer (score 1):

If this is a "Razor Page" it will have a class associated with it which serves as the model and controller of sorts.  It would allow you to set a property on the model via code and then you could reference it in the Razor with Model.DisableSomething, etc.  At it's simpliest it would look something like this:

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        DisableSomething = true;
        return Page();
    }

    public bool DisableSomething {get; set; }

}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model IndexModel

The Model's DisableSomething Property = @Html.Raw(Model.DisableSomething.ToString())
```

Comment: I is the _Layout page which does not have a controller. Is viewbag the answer?

Comment: You could use the ViewData as well.  I have all of my PageModel's inherit from BasePageModel, if there's something that's always shared I have used properties there and then it's accessible in the _Layout (declared with "@model BasePageModel").